# UIDocumentPickerViewController missing cancel button to dismiss when using directoryURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, nsfilemanager, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

We are presenting a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with the URL to the `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier` and for whatever reason, it does not show the cancel button for all our users. Sometimes, it is completely missing and a user cannot dismiss without going to the "Recent" tab where it will force the cancel button to appear.

Here is how we present the modal:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        [self rootDirectoryForICloudWithFolderName:@"Test" createFolder:YES completion:^(NSURL *ubiquityURL) {
            
            self.picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeJPEG] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
            self.picker.directoryURL = ubiquityURL;
            self.picker.delegate = self;
            
            [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
            
        }];
        
    });
    
}

- (void)rootDirectoryForICloudWithFolderName:(NSString *)folderName createFolder:(BOOL)createFolder completion:(void (^)(NSURL *))completionHandler {
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        
        NSURL *rootDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", folderName]];
        if (rootDirectory) {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:rootDirectory.path isDirectory:nil] && createFolder) {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:rootDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
            }
        }
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler(rootDirectory);
        });
    });
}
```

I am setting the directoryURL to the ubiquity URL for the iCloud documents folder for our app. The strange thing is, this only happens on a new install with a unique bundle identifier. If I switch tabs, to make the cancel button appear, then on the next launch it will work correctly. But, changing the bundle identifier will cause the bug to happen again.

**Apple has said this is a bug, but it still remains unfixed in iOS 14 beta 5. Can anyone think of a workaround for this issue as we would love to use this feature!**

Comment: Really just a guess - why not, in your app delegate, ensure the iCloud / root directory exists? The way you describe it sounds as if the presence of the relevant dir, which changes with app identifier, maybe causes it.

Comment: @skaak No, the URL is something like `file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~PickerError/Documents/Test/` and is based on the iCloud Container ID, not the app bundle ID. So, that URL stays the same even if I change the bundle ID.

Comment: Ok - I was hoping that just maybe if the ```file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~PickerError/Documents/``` existed before hand it might solve it but that is a bit of a long shot. Forgive me for just guessing, but maybe don't create the dir in the background since it is not an expensive op and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried to create the dir on the main thread and that didn't help. Sadly.

Comment: Hi Nic - I have the same problem toying with some Swift code in iOS 14 ... I could fix it by editing Info.plist and adding my file type to the list of exported types.

Comment: @skaak Can you post what you used as an answer?

Comment: apologies, I think I commented too fast. I was really just experimenting with some document stuff in the latest Xcode beta 6 and at some stage the little + disappeared. I could get it back by adding my file type to the exported types *and also* by configuring the ```extension UTType``` correctly and too quickly assumed this solves your problem as well. Yous is of course the cancel button - I'd love to experiment with that a bit as well to see if it solves your issue but at present simply don't have the time ... but maybe later ...

Comment: If this helps at all, in the Xcode generated document app, there is this piece of code ```extension UTType
{
 static var myData : UTType
 {
  UTType (importedAs : "com.blahblahblah")
 }
}``` that I had to fix along with setting the exported type in Info.plist to get the + back.